# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ATI HD 3600

Tags: ati, video, software-sources

How can I install my graphics card ATI HD 3600 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS ? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this document, this issue has been adressed there:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonHD